# MEAN update not working from service, only from postman

Tags: angular, mean-stack, crud, postman

I am trying to make an update through a service. If I use postman with the same link as in the service, the update works fine.

Here is my code:

myservice.service.ts:

```
updateUser(userid){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    console.log('http://localhost:3000/users/update/'+ userid);
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/users/update/'+ userid, 
{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
}
```

inside routes/users.js

```
router.put('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
$set: {
  participates: true}
}, 
{
  new: true
},
function(err, updatedUser){
  if(err){
    res.send("Error updating user");
  } else{
    res.json(updatedUser);
  }
}
);
});
```

I do not get an error, but it does not seem to enter the router.put.
What am i missing?

Comment: do you have CORS headers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Comment: I use import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http'; I use const cors = require('cors');app.use(cors()); inside my index.js file

Answer (score 0):

here you have used this url : 'http://localhost:3000/users/update/'+ userid

but in routes you have used : /update/:id,

you have ***/users*** is  not there in your routes,
 just use the same url as you mentioned in service would be good to use in routes, so replace your url in routes with ***/users/update/:id*** , then it will work perfectly..